# Select a subset of observations from a pandas DataFrame using a list of labels

Tags: python, pandas

Given the DataFrame, di,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "Event": ['Biathlon', 'Ski Jump', 'Slalom', 'Downhill'],
    "Award": ['Gold', 'Bronze', 'Gold', 'Silver'],
    "Points":  ['100', '10', '100', '40']
}
d = pd.DataFrame(data)
di = d.set_index(["Award","Event"])

print(di)
                Points
Award  Event          
Gold   Biathlon    100
Bronze Ski Jump     10
Gold   Slalom      100
Silver Downhill     40
```

Let's say I wanted to select all rows with a 'Gold' award in either 'Biathlon' or 'Slalom'... Why does this fail?

```
di.loc[('Gold',['Biathlon','Slalom']),:]
```

Based on an example in the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers), it seems this should work. I've reproduced the example from the docs below:

```
#example from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers

def mklbl(prefix,n):
    return ["%s%s" % (prefix,i)  for i in range(n)]

miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A',4),
                                     mklbl('B',2),
                                     mklbl('C',4),
                                     mklbl('D',2)])

micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','foo'),('a','bar'),
                                                ('b','foo'),('b','bah')],
                                                names=['lvl0', 'lvl1'])

dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(miindex)*len(micolumns)).reshape((len(miindex),len(micolumns))),
index=miindex,
columns=micolumns).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

dfmi.loc[(slice('A1','A3'),slice(None), ['C1','C3']),:]

#this also works
dfmi.loc[(['A1','A3'],['B0','B1'], ['C1','C3']),:]
```

Comment: FWIW, can be simpler to just do `d[ (d.Award == 'Gold') & (d.Event.isin(['Biathlon','Slalom' ])) ]` if you don't otherwise need or want to muck with a multi-index, sorting, etc.

Comment: You're probably right. I'm new to pandas (background is in R) and am just trying to get acquainted with the indexing features of pandas.

Comment: Yeah, you can do a lot with multi-indexes but as this Q&A shows, they are both powerful and (sometimes) tricky to use.  Regardless, you will want to get familiar with simple boolean selections also.  But nothing wrong with the way you tried to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort your index first:

```
In [15]:
data = {
    "Event": ['Biathlon', 'Ski Jump', 'Slalom', 'Downhill'],
    "Award": ['Gold', 'Bronze', 'Gold', 'Silver'],
    "Points":  ['100', '10', '100', '40']
}
d = pd.DataFrame(data)
di = d.set_index(["Award","Event"])
di = di.sort_index()
di

Out[15]:
                Points
Award  Event          
Bronze Ski Jump     10
Gold   Biathlon    100
       Slalom      100
Silver Downhill     40

In [16]:    
di.loc[('Gold',['Biathlon','Slalom']),:]

Out[16]:
               Points
Award Event          
Gold  Biathlon    100
      Slalom      100
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. For others reaching this page, here's a link to the documentation (0.17.1): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex